# Laravel: Using One pivot table id in another pivot table

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm working in a Laravel 7 project. I've implemented my table structure as below:

Programs and Sections many-to-many

progarms

```
name
```

sections

```
name
```

program_section

```
program_id
section_id
```

Teachers and Subjects many-to-many

teachers

```
name
email
designation
```

subjects

```
name
```

subject_teacher

```
subject_id
teacher_id
```

Now, what i want is to use the `program_section` (pivot) `id` inside `subject_teacher` pivot table, so that i can insert the `program_section_id` in `subject_teacher` table and get the program/section of specific teacher/subject.

Any idea how to do this using `Laravel Eloquent` ?

Comment: Hey, ever found a solution to this?

Comment: how about now? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use many to many relation on laravel, try to read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)